# how to specifically control the smoothness of scrolling in Windows?

Tags: mouse, notepad++, scrolling, sublime-text-2, scroll-wheel

There are some applications like Sublime Text, Notepad++, or Netbeans on which the touch-pad scrolling of the laptop doesn't work effectively. If I try to scroll using the two finger touch, the whole page scrolls to the end on the slightest movement. How can this issue be resolved? The settings of the individual application were not at all helpful.
NOTE: Changing the Windows settings doesn't affect the applications at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Window 10, 
Go to

`Start>Setting>Devices>Mouse & touchpad`

There are several options regarding controlling how many lines to scroll each time.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: It is working fine with me in notepad++. Please be more specific.

Comment: Changing the settings doesn't at all affect the application. Even if I fasten the scrolling, the application still behaves the same way. If scroll slightly with two fingers, it automatically reaches the end of the page. If I scroll very finely only then it scrolls properly. This is quite undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This worked for me on Windows 10:

1. Press the Windows key and search for 'Mouse Settings'
2. Under 'Roll the mouse wheel to scroll', set it the 'multiple lines at a time'
3. Under 'Choose how man lines to scroll each time', set it to 1
4. Restart Notepad++